# Homogeneity does not suffice for a map between vector spaces to be linear

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, examples-counterexamples

The following problem is taken from *Sheldon Axler*'s book *Linear Algebra Done Right*, more precisely *Exercise 1.* from *Chapter 3*:

**Problem**: Give an example of a function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(av) = af(v)$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ but $f$ is not linear.

I tried to include things like absolute values and square roots in order to handle the homogeneity, but I did not had any success in constructing such an example yet by doing so.

Do you know such an example? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you drawn pictures of what homogeneity does and does not require of the function? Not every function has to be given by a formula.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished working on this problem and this is what I got:

Let

$$ f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}\\ 
(x,y) \mapsto \begin{cases} 
 \frac{x^2}{y} \ , \   y \neq 0 \\
0 \  , \ y=0 \end{cases} $$
This is a homogeneous map since $$f\Bigl(a(x,y)\Bigr) = f\Bigl((ax,ay)\Bigr) = a\ \frac{x^2}{y} = af\Bigl((x,y)\Bigr)$$ whenever $a \neq 0$ and in the case of $a=0$ we get:
$$f\Bigl(\ 0(x,y)\ \Bigr) = f\Bigl((0,0)\Bigr) = 0 = 0f\Bigl((x,y)\Bigr)$$
However, it is not additive, in general, since $$f\Bigl((x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)\Bigr) = \frac{(x_1 + x_2)^2}{y_1+y_2} \neq \frac{x_1^2}{y_1}+\frac{x_2^2}{y_2} = f\Bigl((x_1,y_1)\Bigr)+f\Bigl((x_2,y_2)\Bigr)$$ hence not linear.

Answer (score -1):

consider the map: $$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}\\ (x,y) \mapsto \begin{cases} 
 x \text{ if } y=0 \\
0 \text{ else }\end{cases} $$
then this is homogenous $f(a(x,y))(f(ax,ay))=\begin{cases}ax \text{ if } y=0 \\ a0\text{ else }\end{cases}$, but not linear, since $$f(1,1)+f(1,-1)=0 +0 = 0 \neq f(2,0) =f((1,1)+(1,-1)).$$

Comment: You say "this is clearly homogeneous", but it can't be (in the sense given in the problem) unless your norm is constantly zero. Otherwise, there's no way for it to send $-v$ to $-f(v)$ as norms never output negative numbers.

Comment: sorry, you are completely right, I think i remmedied that, I was just very tempted by the simplicity of the norm.